# Mongoose remove objects from array of objects based on some filter

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, pull

I have a schema like this:

```
var resortSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
name: String,
price: String,
reviews: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Review"
    }
]});


var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rating: {
        // Setting the field type
        type: Number,
        // Defining min and max values
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        // Adding validation to see if the entry is an integer
        validate: {
            // validator accepts a function definition which it uses for validation
            validator: Number.isInteger,
            message: "{VALUE} is not an integer value."
        }
    },
    // author id and username fields
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    // resort associated with the review
    resort: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Resort"
    }
});
```

In code I have populated reviews array in the resorts document, and I want to delete just some specific reviews (based on author ID) from the resort.reviews array. Something like:

```
resort.reviews.pull({"author.id": someSpecificUserID});
resort.save();
```

But this does not work. How do I do that?

**EDIT:**
I can find all reviews by a specific user id, but I do not know how to also filter by the resort.
I tried this:

```
console.log("req.user._id: " + typeof req.user._id); // object
console.log("req.params.id: " + typeof req.params.id); // string
console.log("ObjectId: " + typeof mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id));

var resortObjectID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);

// Get ids of reviews matching a particular author
const reviews = await Review.find({ "author.id": req.user._id, "resort": resortObjectID });
console.log("reviews: " + reviews);     // reviews is []. if I remove "resort": resortObjectID I do get all the reviews of that user in all resorts. But I need to filter to only one resort.

//Pass review ids to $pull     // I am not sure if this works yet
await Resort.updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    { $pull: { reviews: { $in: reviews.map(x=>x._id) } } },
    { multi: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

As both collections ( `resort and review` ) are different, pulling value from one collection based on the value of other collections will simply not work. So you will first have to get Ids of the reviews you want to delete from `review` collection and then pass them to `$pull`

```
 1. Get ids of reviews matching a particular author
    
    const reviews = await db.review.find({"author.id": <someSpecificUserID>}, {_id: 1});

 2. Pass review ids to $pull

    await db.resort.update(
    { },
    { $pull: { reviews: { $in: reviews.map(x=>x._id) } } },
    { multi: true })
```

Comment: Not really. I edited the original post and added some more code.